# Show that $P(X_{n+1}\notin \{0,N\}|X_n = i) \leq 1-2(\frac{1}{N})^N$

Tags: probability-theory

**Problem:**

Given that $X_n \sim Bin(N,\frac{i}{N})$ and $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a Markov chain with values in $\{0, ... N\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}.$ Assume that $X_0 = i_0 \in \{0, ... ,N\}$ is a constant. For $i,j = 0, ... , N$ the following is true:

$$P(X_{n+1}=j|X_n = i)={N \choose j}(\frac{i}{N})^j(1-\frac{i}{N})^{N-j}$$

Show that for all $n\geq 0, \text{ and } i=1, ... ,N-1$
$$P(X_{n+1}\notin \{0,N\}|X_n = i) \leq 1-2(\frac{1}{N})^N$$

**Attempt:**
$$P(X_{n+1}\notin \{0,N\}|X_n = i)=1-P(X_{n+1}\in \{0,N\}|X_n =1-P(\{X_{n+1}=0\} \cup \{X_{n+1}=N\}|X_n = i)=$$
$$\stackrel{A\cap B = Ø}{=}1-(P(X_{n+1}=0|X_n = i)+P(X_{n+1}=N|X_n = i))=1-((1-\frac{i}{N})^N + (\frac{i}{N})^N)$$

That's where i'm stranded. As you can see i'm missing a inequality and the true result...

One idea i had is forcing an inequlity by concluding that:

Choose $i=1:$

$$1-((1-\frac{1}{N})^N + (\frac{1}{N})^N)\leq 1-2(\frac{1}{N})^N$$

But it seems wrong, somehow.

Does anybody have another idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already shown that
$$P(X_{n+1}\in \{0, N\}\mid X_n=i) = \left(1-\frac iN\right)^N +\left(\frac iN\right)^N.
$$
But each term on the RHS is at least $(\frac1N)^N$, since $N-i\ge 1$ and $i\ge 1$. This completes the proof.

Comment: P({me solving the question})=1